# Loop though ArrayLists with different types to get data sorted

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist

If I have the following ArrayLists :

```
// Orders
List<Order> orders = OrderDao.getInstance(context).getPostedOrders(merchantId);
// Payments
List<Payment> payments = PaymentDao.getInstance(context).getPayments(merchantId);
// Cheques
List<Cheque> cheques = ChequeDao.getInstance(context).getCheques(merchantId);
```

Each object has a creationDate, how do I go through all and print them sorted by that creationDate, for generating merchant summary :

for example:

```
01/6 payment1
01/6 order1
03/6 order2
05/6 payment2
09/6 cheque1
12/6 order3
```

...

Or if there is another way to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tired so far?

Comment: Sorted each of them seperately, calculated total size and looped through all, once there is an object, compare all and print the less date.

Comment: @BilalHalayqa plz elaborate your question ..Its not unclear what u r doing with this code and whats ur problem..i can just see u are retrieving list of orders,payments and checks....what u want to do next ?

Comment: @smrutiranjan I want to loop through all of them and print them by date, each object has Date field. See the example please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe letting Order, Payment andCheque implement an interface

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    Date getCreationDate();

    String getName();
}
```

And then

```
List<MyInterface> list = OrderDao.getInstance(context).getPostedOrders(merchantId);        

list.addAll(PaymentDao.getInstance(context).getPayments(merchantId));

list.addAll(ChequeDao.getInstance(context).getCheques(merchantId));
```

Answer (score 1):

Let them implement a common interface(getCreationDate(), getName(), etc.) and add them all to a List of that interface.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a `SortedMap<Date, String> map = new TreeMap<>()` with dates mapped to summary texts. Then iterate over the map entries, which will be sorted by date, and format the output appropriately.